# Open source jabber based website "live chat" / "live help" system?

Tags: open-source, xmpp, ajax, instant-messaging

I don't know if this belongs on SF, SU or SO... let's try SF first.

I'm looking for a "live help" system for website which uses Jabber/XMPP as a backend... so that website visitors could click a "Chat Now" button, and using AJAX, chat with operators who are already set up using Jabber accounts. Something very much like [J-Livesupport](http://www.j-livesupport.com/) but without a jabber server (I already have one) and preferably OSS/free.

[Openfire's](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) Fastpath Webchat is perfect except you *must* use Openfire's Spark client. No dice there.

Before I build my own, anyone know of anything out there?

Comment: @josh - hope you didn't build your own - openfire will definitely work with pidgin

Comment: @josh - I've removed my answer. I was so accustomed to using both pidgin and spark at the same time with Openfire that I had forgotten that Openfire wasn't sending my webbased helpdesk requests to pidgin.  We get the web chats through spark and chat about the requests internally using pidgin (or adium).  When I sat down to list out the steps this weekend the limitation became obvious.  Sorry I got your hopes up.

Comment: @Patrick R, thanks, I was hopeful, but some of @joschi's suggestions look promising, so I hope one of those comes to maturity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

- [MUCkl](http://blog.jwchat.org/muckl/)
- [Tigase Minichat](http://www.tigase.org/en/project/minichat)
- [Speeqe](http://code.stanziq.com/speeqe/)

All of them rely on an existing XMPP server with HTTP-poll or HTTP-bind.

Comment: Tigase and Speeqe sound promising!

Comment: None of these actually worked reliably but they look promising and so I award you the best answer. Hopefully they will be better in the near future!

Answer (score 0):

I have used other jabber clients with openfire before, pidgin specifically. I know they work. I have not used the webchat plugin though.

Comment: With openfire Fastpath?

Answer (score 0):

you can try http://www.plupper.com ... it's pretty mature tool with lot of additional features.

Comment: Thanks... but I was looking for something which would integrate with an existing jabber server.